# Android phone and PC is hacked. How to ensure that it won't be hacked again?

Tags: android, desktop-computer

My android and PC has been hacked. Apps are being manipulated. Private data is remotely fetched. Files and photos from my PC are also fetched. The apps are being manipulated in runtime as well.

I work from home. So my most important data is on phone and PC. I am a poet and a blogger. The most intimidating issue is I found changes in my drafts which I didn't make. Also some drafts are missing. I am really terrified.

**My question:** 
Can I get back the full control and saftety to store my data privately again? There must be some solution, how to get back full control of phone and computer again? How to prevent data from theft after reset?

Thanks.

Comment: Anybody giving negative votes, request you to post the reason so I can edit my question. Thank you.

Comment: I expect people are down voting (I didn't) because the only way to prevent manipulations is to isolate the systems from the Internet, which people here will think is obvious.  Similarly, getting full control and safety back requires resetting everything to factory defaults, upgrading to latest software versions and re-adding documents)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disconnect them from internet. When they're offline, they cannot receive commands and send data. After that, you can safely ponder around trying to figure out what application exactly is causing the problem (because every single action a computer does is due to some application). Or nuke it from orbit, depending on how much time you have and how much you care about data

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail? I didn't get how to check applications in computer?

Answer (score 2):

You have to secure your devices first by isolating them from the internet access and any wireless communications. Once done, do not turn them off and run a system monitor and set to record every process going on and switch to internet access again. Cut the internet access again once you have collected enough data. Now analyse the logs for any unusual activity. Remove the infected files and programs.
Hopefully if you still have access to your accounts change their passwords and use stronger passwords. Enabling 2-factor authentication and disabling IPv6 protocol would be good countermeasures.
Inbox for further help.

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to do this, and no step-by-step procedure as the exact steps vary depending on your circumstance.  To solve the problem you need to realise -

- From a technical POV once someone else has control of your computer/pjone you can't assume you can resecure it without fully erasing and rebooting it (sometimes not even then, but don't worry about that for now)
- Your entire network could be compromised (because more then 1 device is).  That means you can't trust any devices in the network - including your router.

Thus the general solution is to disconnect your network from the Internet, back up everything, reinstall everything from scratch (offline), add antivirus and anti malware software, manually inspect and copy docs/pics (not programs) from backup.